# Javascript "OOP" and prototypes with multiple-level inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I'm new to Javascript programming and I'm approaching my first application (a game, indeed) from an object oriented programming perspective (I know js is not really object oriented, but for this particular problem it was easier for me to start like this).

I have a hierarchy of "classes" where the top-most ("Thing" class) defines a list of related things (attached items in the game). It's inherited by a ThingA class which is inherited by ThingA1 and ThingA2 classes.

The minimal example would be:

```
function Thing() 
{
  this.relatedThings   = [];
}
Thing.prototype.relateThing = function(what)
{
  this.relatedThings.push(what);
}

ThingA.prototype = new Thing();
ThingA.prototype.constructor = ThingA;
function ThingA()
{
}

ThingA1.prototype = new ThingA();
ThingA1.prototype.constructor = ThingA1;
function ThingA1()
{

}

ThingA2.prototype = new ThingA();
ThingA2.prototype.constructor = ThingA2;
function ThingA2()
{    
}

var thingList = [];

thingList.push(new ThingA());
thingList.push(new ThingA1());
thingList.push(new ThingA2());
thingList.push(new ThingA2());
thingList.push(new Thing());

thingList[1].relateThing('hello');
```

At the end of the code, when the relateThing is executed, every ThingA, ThingA1 and ThingA2 is going to execute it (not the last "Thing" object in the array). I've found if I define the relateThing function in the ThingA prototype, it will work right. Because of how the game is designed I'll prefer not to have to do that.

Maybe I'm not understanding something about how the prototypes work in javascript. I know the function is shared among all the objects, but i guess the execution would be individual. Could somebody explain why is this happening and how to solve it? I don't know if I'm doing the inheritance wrong, or the prototypes definitions, or what.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JavaScript is pretty much based on objects, so why should it not be object oriented?

Comment: As far as I've learned about javascript, prototypal languages are not exactly the same as object oriented languages (there are no classes, etc), although the concept could be similar. But I'm not an expert.

Comment: The fact that JavaScript is strongly object oriented doesn't meen it works the same way as other OO languages. In fact, inheritance is ill supported. Many libraries implement advanced ways which really are workarounds the improve how inheritance works. One of the bests currently I found is that of John Resig's which is based on the Prototype and base2 libraries but further improved. http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

Comment: Is your code not working as expected ? Didn't understand what the result you wanted and what u got instead

Comment: @Joel_Blum After the execution all the objects have a "hello" inside their respective relatedThings array. I would have expected only thingList[1] would have it.

Comment: @neverbot: [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) does not mean you have to have [classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-based_programming), [prototype-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) is OOP as well

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Welcome to the prototype chain!

Let's see what it looks like in your example.

#### The Problem

When you call `new Thing()`, you are creating a new object with a property `relatedThings` which refers to an array. So we can say we have this:

```
+--------------+
|Thing instance|
|              |
| relatedThings|----> Array
+--------------+
```

You are then assigning this instance to `ThingA.prototype`:

```
+--------------+
|    ThingA    |      +--------------+
|              |      |Thing instance|
|   prototype  |----> |              |
+--------------+      | relatedThings|----> Array
                      +--------------+
```

So each instance of `ThingA` will inherit from the `Thing` instance. Now you are going to create `ThingA1` and `ThingA2` and assign a new `ThingA` instance to each of their prototypes, and later create instances of `ThingA1` and `ThingA2` (and `ThingA` and `Thing`, but not shown here).

The relationship is now this (`__proto__` is an *internal* property, connecting an object with its prototype):

```
                               +-------------+
                               |   ThingA    |
                               |             |    
+-------------+                |  prototype  |----+
|   ThingA1   |                +-------------+    |
|             |                                   |
|  prototype  |---> +--------------+              |
+-------------+     |    ThingA    |              |
                    | instance (1) |              |
                    |              |              |
+-------------+     |  __proto__   |--------------+ 
|   ThingA1   |     +--------------+              |
|   instance  |           ^                       |
|             |           |                       v
|  __proto__  |-----------+                 +--------------+
+-------------+                             |Thing instance|
                                            |              |
                                            | relatedThings|---> Array
+-------------+     +--------------+        +--------------+ 
|   ThingA2   |     |   ThingA     |              ^
|             |     | instance (2) |              |
|  prototype  |---> |              |              |
+-------------+     |  __proto__   |--------------+
                    +--------------+
+-------------+           ^
|   ThingA2   |           |  
|   instance  |           |
|             |           |
|  __proto__  |-----------+
+-------------+
```

And because of that, every instance of `ThingA`, `ThingA1` or `ThingA2` **refers to one and the same array instance**.

This is **not** what you want!

---

#### The Solution

To solve this problem, each instance of any "subclass" should have *its own* `relatedThings` property. You can achieve this by calling the parent constructor in each child constructor, similar to calling `super()` in other languages:

```
function ThingA() {
    Thing.call(this);
}

function ThingA1() {
    ThingA.call(this);
}

// ...
```

This calls `Thing` and `ThingA` and sets `this` inside those function to the first argument you pass to `.call`. Learn more about [`.call` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`this` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

This alone will change the above picture to:

```
                               +-------------+
                               |   ThingA    |
                               |             |    
+-------------+                |  prototype  |----+
|   ThingA1   |                +-------------+    |
|             |                                   |
|  prototype  |---> +--------------+              |
+-------------+     |    ThingA    |              |
                    | instance (1) |              |
                    |              |              |
                    | relatedThings|---> Array    |
+-------------+     |  __proto__   |--------------+ 
|   ThingA1   |     +--------------+              |
|   instance  |           ^                       |
|             |           |                       |
|relatedThings|---> Array |                       v
|  __proto__  |-----------+                 +--------------+
+-------------+                             |Thing instance|
                                            |              |
                                            | relatedThings|---> Array
+-------------+     +--------------+        +--------------+ 
|   ThingA2   |     |   ThingA     |              ^
|             |     | instance (2) |              |
|  prototype  |---> |              |              |
+-------------+     | relatedThings|---> Array    |
                    |  __proto__   |--------------+
                    +--------------+
+-------------+           ^
|   ThingA2   |           |  
|   instance  |           |
|             |           |
|relatedThings|---> Array | 
|  __proto__  |-----------+
+-------------+
```

As you can see, each instance has its own `relatedThings` property, which refers to a different array instance. There are still `relatedThings` properties in the prototype chain, but they are all *shadowed* by the instance property.

---

#### Better Inheritance

Also, don't set the prototype with:

```
ThingA.prototype = new Thing();
```

You actually don't want to create a new `Thing` instance here. What would happen if `Thing` expected arguments? Which one would you pass? What if calling the `Thing` constructor has side effects?

What you *actually* want is to hook up `Thing.prototype` into the prototype chain. You can do this with [`Object.create` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create):

```
ThingA.prototype = Object.create(Thing.prototype);
```

Anything that happens when the constructor (`Thing`) is executed will happen later, when we actually create a new `ThingA` instance (by calling `Thing.call(this)` as shown above).

Comment: Well.  I'll just stop writing what I was going to write. Solid response. +1

Comment: @Felix : Impressive response, i'm testing now. Just another question: I change the way I set the prototype, but should be the constructor specified the same way I'm doing?

i.e:     ThingA.prototype.constructor = ThingA;

Comment: @neverbot: Well, I hope it helps, maybe it's too confusing :D Setting `constructor` is not *required* because no internal method makes use of it, but it is good practice.

Comment: Nice explanation. +1 for the effort.

Comment: Nice diagrams. For the last section, there are some excellent answers going into the details at [What is the reason *(not)* to use the 'new' keyword here?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the way prototyping works in JavaScript in order to achieve a simple way of inheritance and OOP, I'd suggest taking a look at this:  https://github.com/haroldiedema/joii

It basically allows you to do the following (and more):

```
// First (bottom level)
var Person = new Class(function() {
    this.name = "Unknown Person";
});

// Employee, extend on Person & apply the Role property.
var Employee = new Class({ extends: Person }, function() {
    this.name = 'Unknown Employee';
    this.role = 'Employee';
});

// 3rd level, extend on Employee. Modify existing properties.
var Manager = new Class({ extends: Employee }, function() {

    // Overwrite the value of 'role'.
    this.role = 'Manager';

    // Class constructor to apply the given 'name' value.
    this.__construct = function(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
});

// And to use the final result:
var myManager = new Manager("John Smith");
console.log( myManager.name ); // John Smith
console.log( myManager.role ); // Manager
```

Answer (score 0):

In OOP, when you're are defining a constructor of a sub class you are also (implicitly or explicitly) choosing a constructor from the super type. When a sub object is constructed both constructor are executed, first that from the super class, the all the other down the hierarchy.

In javascript this must be explicitly called and don't come automatically!

```
function Thing() {
  this.relatedThings = [];
}
Thing.prototype.relateThing = function(what){
  this.relatedThings.push(what);
}

function ThingA(){
  Thing.call(this);
}
ThingA.prototype = new Thing();

function ThingA1(){
  ThingA.call(this);
}
ThingA1.prototype = new ThingA();

function ThingA2(){
  ThingA.call(this);

}
ThingA2.prototype = new ThingA();
```

If you don't this way, all the instance of ThingA, ThingA1 and ThingA2 shere the same relatedThings array constructed in the Thing constructor and called once for all instance at line:

```
ThingA.prototype = new Thing();
```

Globally, infact, in your code, you have only 2 calls to the Thing constructor and this result in only 2 instances of the relatedThings array.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Thank for advice, I corrected. I read yours too, congrats :)