# Javascript inheritance of constructor with variables

Tags: javascript, oop, object, inheritance

Let's say I have

```
function Point(x, y)
{
    this.X = x;
    this.Y = y;
}
```

and I want to have a class Point2. Using [this](http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/OOPinJS2.html) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) I came up with this code:

```
function Point2(x, y)
{
    this.X = x; // <-
    this.Y = y; // <-
}

Point2.prototype = new Point();
Point2.prototype.constructor = Point;
```

However, if I have many variables or many inheritances, I don't want to repeat the assignment of properties all the time (see the lines with `<-`. If I write it like this, like it says in the second link:

```
Point2.call(this);
```

, I get an error: Maximum call stack size exceeded, because it calls itself, which looked suspicious for me from the start.

**So, is there a way to call the parent constructor with the same incoming values instead of repeating the whole code?**

Comment: Your inheritance is wrong.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15045616/34397

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the **parent** constructor, not your own constructor:

```
Point.call(this, x, y);
```

If the arguments are always the same, you can also write `Point.apply(this, arguments);`

Comment: Great, that did the job, also thanks for the `apply` for all arguments!