# A JavaScript inheritance example

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

For example, I have a person constructor as follows:

```
function Person(name) {
    var username = name;
    return {
        getName: function() {return username;},
        setName: function(name) {username=name;}
    }
}
```

Then I want to create another `Employee` constructor which would inherit from the `Person` constructor and has a `getId` method that returns an auto-incremented id value for every object created out of the `Employee` constructor. For example,

```
var employee1 = new Employee('foo');
employee1.getName() // will output foo
employee1.getId() // will output 1
var employee2 = new Employee('qoo');
employee2.getName() // will output qoo
employee2.getId() // will output 2
```

The problem is I'm a little bit confused about how to create an `id` variable on `Employee` constructor that it only gets called once and then each object will get a fixed auto-incremented value. How should I set up the `Employee` constructor and the inheritance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your `Person` constructor, you do not want to use prototypal inheritance but parasitic one.

The `Employee` constructor will be quite similar in the regard of creating local variables and defining local functions, only that the `id` will be initialized by incrementing a static counter instead of a paramter:

```
Employee.counter = 0;
function Employee(name) {
    var that = Person(name);
    var id = Employee.counter++;
    that.getId = function() { return id; };
    return that;
}
```

Comment: The reason that you think I don't wanna use prototypal inheritance but parasitic one is because??

Comment: Because you return an object literal from the `Person` function, instead of using it as a constructor; and you don't use the `.prototype` at all (although you admittedly cannot in this example).

Comment: Except for the odd `defineProperties`, it would look like [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045080/javascript-inheritance-calling-object-create-when-setting-a-prototype) with prototypal inheritance. You'd define the `getId`/`getName`/`setName` methods on `this` and call `Person` differently, but how `id` is created stays the same.