# Inheritence of variable properties

Tags: javascript, inheritance

From an exercise at codeacademy:

```
function Penguin(name) {
    this.name = "Pingy";
    this.numLegs = 2;
}

// create your Emperor class here and make it inherit from Penguin
function Emperor (name){
    this.name = name;
}
Emperor.prototype = new Penguin();
var emp = new Emperor("Empy");
```

So I made `Emperor` inherit properties from `Penguin`, now I know that `emp.numLegs` will be 2.

After reading the comments I edited the question:
As you can see I gave a name upon creating `emp`, and `emp.name` will indeed be the name of my new emp, which is "Empy". But what about the `name` inherited from the Penguin class constructor? Where does it go?

Comment: Try it? Actually have a name in your construction call for Emperor and see what value you get.

Comment: Hint: there will be two `name`s in the prototype chain of `emp`. But only one of them is `emp.name`. Namely the one that is a property of `emp`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Codecademy is a great way for beginners to learn JavaScript. Learning any programming language takes practice, and Codecademy makes you practice.

Sometimes however you need to go beyond the scope of the practicals and learn some theory. Read the following answer. It explains prototypal inheritance in JavaScript really well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743

Now you have a `Penguin` constructor as follows:

```
function Penguin(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.numLegs = 2;
}
```

Then you create an `Emperor` constructor which inherits from `Penguin`:

```
function Emperor(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Emperor.prototype = new Penguin();
```

Notice that you're creating an instance of `Penguin` and assigning it to `Emperor.prototype`. Hence:

1. `Emperor.prototype.name = undefined` - this is because you're not passing any `name` to the `Penguin` constructor. If I'd written `Emperor.prototype = new Penguin("Empy")` then `Emperor.prototype.name` would be `"Empy"`.
2. `Emperor.prototype.numLegs = 2` - obviously.

Now when you create a new `Emperor` as follows you need to give the constructor a name (remember that you're inheriting `undefined` from `Penguin` as a name). Hence:

```
var emp = new Emperor("Empy");
```

**That was the old school method.**

Nowadays JavaScript programmers use `Object.create` and `call` to inherit from another constructor. Let me explain with an example:

```
function Emperor(name) {
    Penguin.call(this, name);
}

Emperor.prototype = Object.create(Penguin.prototype);
Emperor.prototype.constructor = Emperor;
```

This method has several advantages over the old school method:

1. Instead of creating a new instance of `Penguin` using `new Penguin()` and passing no arguments to it, we inherit the prototype members of `Penguin` using `Object.create(Penguin.prototype)`. This also prevent unnecessary initialization of the base constructor until the derived constructor is actually called.
2. Instead of writing `this.name = name` in the derived constructor again we call the base constructor using `Penguin.call(this, name)` which does it for us. Such a pattern is called a mixin and is very useful if the base constructor needs to be initialized at runtime or needs to maintain its own state information.

Note that we have also added an additional statement `Emperor.prototype.constructor = Emperor`. This is because `prototype` is a very special property which exists on all functions. It points to an object which has a very special `constructor` property which points to the function itself. By setting `Emperor.prototype` to something else we lose this property. Hence we set it again.

The net effect in both these examples is the same. However for more complex code it's much better to use the new method. Happy learning JavaScript.

Comment: There is actually an important difference in behavior between the two methods. In the old method, all `Emperor` instances share the reference to `numLegs`, so changing one will affect everyone. (In other words, all emperor penguins have the same number of legs.) With the new version, the value is copied into the instance instead of referring to a copy in the prototype.

Comment: @Hjulle Indeed. However, you shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: I'd argue that it's nothing inherently wrong with modifying an inherited property. We'd get the same problem even if the parent had a setter. What you definitely shouldn't do is putting anything but methods in the prototype (which the first method does). That is just a recipe for disaster. At least if you do not make sure that the properties are not modifiable. (Or actually want a global mutable state that is shared between instances, but it's a pretty obscure/confusing way to do it.)

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are wondering why you have to provide `name` as parameter to `Emperor` and `this.name = name;` inside the constructor.

Prototype inheritance in JavaScript is very simple, there is no hidden magic going on. The only connection you provided between `Emperor` and `Penguin` is in this line:

```
Emperor.prototype = new Penguin();
```

`Emperor.prototype` is now an instance of `Penguin`, but it could be **any object** for that matter. The *function* `Emperor` does not know anything about the function `Penguin`, so it does not magically call `Penguin`.

When you call a function (`Func`) with `new`, all it does is creating a new empty object, whose prototype is the functions `prototype` property (`Func.prototype`). This object will become the `this` value inside the constructor and will be returned implicitly if no other object is returned.

> But what about the name inherited from the Penguin class constructor? Where does it go?

It's a property of `Emperor.prototype` and is shadowed by each `Emperor` instance's `name` property.

Have a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040955/javascript-oop-and-prototypes-with-multiple-level-inheritance/15041274#15041274) where I created some nice ASCII charts explaining the relation between instances and their prototypes.

---

**Note:** `Emperor.prototype = new Penguin();` is actually not a good way of establishing the inheritance. What happens if `Penguin` *requires*  an argument? What would pass?

At this moment you actually don't want to create a new instance of `Penguin`, you only want to hook up `Penguin`'s `prototype` into the prototype chain. You can do this easily with `Object.create`:

```
Emperor.prototype = Object.create(Penguin.prototype);
Emperor.prototype.constructor = Emperor;
```

But then new `Emperor` objects wouldn't have a `numLegs` property anymore. That's why you have to call the `Penguin` on each new `Emperor` instance, just like do in other languages with `super()`:

```
function Emperor (name){
    Penguin.call(this, name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When calling `new Penguin()`, this method will create an object and return the prototype of that object.

When doing prototype inhertance, the only thing you do is creating a new `Penguin` object first and put those values inside the prototype of `Emperor`. Now, when you are creating a new `Emperor` object, the prototype is already set to the values of `Penguin`. To override those, you need to set these again in a new constructor.

Inhertiance in JavaScript is very different from other languages.

A code example:

```
function Penguin(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.legs = 2;
}

function Emperor(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Emperor.prototype = new Penguin();
/**
 * The prototype of Emperor now contains:
 * 
       {
           "name": undefined,
           "legs": 2
       }
 * 
 * Because you didn't add an argument to the constructor of `Penguin`
 */

var e = new Emperor('foo');
// The name property will get overriden with 'foo'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Penguin` object also when created requires a name to be passes into the `name` parameter. So when you create a new object of type `Penguin` you have to pass the name. Similarly since `Emperor` inherits from the `Penguin` object you have to pass the value in the constructor so that if you wish to do a different processing than that which happens in the base class `Penguin` you can define it so in the sub class constructor. But `Emperor` can be an object object of any type since it has no information on definition of `Penguin`.

If in the definition of the class 'Emperor' you remove the line

```
 this.name = name;
```

Then you can pass any variable in the constructor and still get the value "Pingy" as defined in the super constructor

and if you add the line

```
 Penguin.call(this, name) ;// As to call super class instance
```

Then you get the value passed properly onto the new object with the `numLegs` as 2 also