# Weird moment of JS Inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

Here is my superclass:

```
function Element() {
   var name;
   this.setName(n) = func()...{};
   this.getName() = func()..{return name};
}
```

My another child class:

```
Select = null;
...
Select =
   function (n) {
       if (typeof n !== "undefined")
          this.setName(n);
   ...
}
Select.prototype = new Element();
Select.prototype.constructor = Select;
```

So, what kind of "weird moment" am I talking about? Here it is:

```
var e1 = new Select("element1");
e1.getName();  // return "element1"
var e2 = new Select();  // WITHOUT NAME
e2.getName();  // return "element1"!!! should be ""!
```

This is a fairly predictable behavior, but how to get around this?
Of course, i can make something like a `this.clear()` in `Element`, that will clear properties and put this method in `Select` function, but maybe there is a proper solution?

Comment: Don't like private properties.

Comment: @wared yeeh awesome solution)

Comment: You should add this line `Element.call(this, n)` into `Select`.

Comment: I know. I would say that there is no access modifier in javascript and I personally don't see any good reason to mimic such a feature.

Comment: a big thank to you, @wared. Please, make a full answer with `Element.call(this, n)` and i'll make it accepted.

Comment: I'm playing with your code and I realize that there is a mistake : `this.setName() = function () {}` throws `ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`. You have to remove the first pair of parenthesis.

Comment: More on how to inherit and use constructor functions can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941 like how to re use parent constructor and why you should not create an instance of Parent to set up the prototype part of Child.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Define Private field Members and Inheritance in JAVASCRIPT module pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463040/define-private-field-members-and-inheritance-in-javascript-module-pattern)

Comment: Btw, you might consider not overwriting the global [`Element` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)…

Comment: @wingsofovnia Updated : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21715156/1636522. Hope this is clear enough - I took the opportunity to practice my English...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add this line `Element.call(this, n)` into `Select`. It's quite hard to explain and I feel grumpy because I don't like fake private properties in javascript, but well, I must provide some details in order for you to understand what you are currently doing, otherwise I will not be able to get to sleep.

So, doing `new Element()` creates a new context where `name` can live without disturbing anyone. Additionally, two new functions called `setName` and `getName` are created, and bound to the `prototype` object of `Select`.

From now on, if you create a new instance of `Select`, you can call these functions since they are available in the prototype of the instance. This actually happens doing `new Select("element1")`. Indeed, `n` is defined, so, `setName` is called from `this`, which refers to the instance.

But most importantly, calling `setName` with `n` set to `"element1"` will also set `name` to `"element1"`. Then, if you create a second instance of `Select`, without defining `n`, `setName` is not called, so, `name` remains set to `"element1"`, *for both instances*.

Why *for both instances*? Because both instances share the same `setName` method, the one bound to the prototype, and this method refers to a unique `name` variable - remember that `Element` was called only once.

Finally, why this new line `Element.call(this, n)` prevents `name` from being shared? Because each call to `Element` creates a new context, that is to say, a new `name`, a new `setName` and a new `getName`, and binds these two methods to the newly created instance.

Well, hope this is the morning for you, I would be sorry if you get into sleeping disorders by my fault...

---

As mentionned by [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714707/weird-moment-of-js-inheritance/21715156#comment32838801_21715156) and [HMR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714707/weird-moment-of-js-inheritance/21715156#comment32838114_21714707), this way of creating the prototype - `Child.prototype = new Parent` - is out of fashion and will lead you to a dead end. Keep in mind that the prototype is kind of a template for creating instances. Knowing this and considering your code, we can make at least two observations :

1. As you know, a constructor is intended to initialize instances. In your case, the initialization process - what's inside `Element` - is unnecessarily executed since the goal is currently to set the template upon which instances will be created.
2. Let's say that `name` is required in `new Element(name)`, otherwise your program crashes. What kind of name would you give to the prototype? This question is obviously useless, since you would not want to give a name to a template.

To bypass these problems you need a middleman as shown in the below code (copied from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12593269/1636522) shared by Bergi). As you can see, the creation of the prototype is delegated to a "dummy" constructor which is empty. Doing so allows to resolve the two problems raised above.

```js
function Dummy () {}
Dummy.prototype = Element.prototype;
Select.prototype = new Dummy();
Select.prototype.constructor = Select;
```

Alternatively, you could use the built-in `Object.create()` :

```
Select.prototype = Object.create(Element.prototype);
Select.prototype.constructor = Select;
```

---

Further reading :

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15461601/1636522
- http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/

Comment: Also, `Element` should actually be [never called instead of once with `new`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the prototype of `Element` so the variables are not shared between the instances:

```
function Element() {}    
Element.prototype.setName = function(n) { this.name = n; };
Element.prototype.getName = function() { return this.name; };
```

In this case `e2.getName()` will return `undefined`.

Comment: With this approach the name variable would be exposed.

Comment: @Péter And it does not change anything since, even private, the variable is still mutable through `setName`. This is why I feel grumpy :D +1 Dan Lee.

Comment: Yes, but we don't saw the the source of the setName method and I thought @wingsofovnia choose this structre on purpose.

Comment: @Péter OP did not mention that the variable has to be private (we're just assuming here). It's just another viable solution.

Comment: @Péter I wasn't blaming you, I just wanted to take the opportunity to detail my point of view. That would be great to have some clarifications from the OP.

Comment: That's right. We can only make assumptions. I just assumed based on the structure of his code, the comment (2nd comment to reply the 1st) and the answer he accepted.