# Prototype inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototype

I've written the following "class" in javascript:

```
var On = {

    Request: {
        User: function() {
            _Login = function() {console.log('Let me see.')};
        }
    },
    User: function() {},
    Article: function() {},
    Comment: function() {}

};


On.User.prototype = {

    constructor: function() { On.Request.User.call(this)},

    Create: function(username, password, email) { 
        username = username || null;
        password = password || null;
        email = email || null;

        //here I want to call _Login from Request.user
    },

    Login: function(username, password) { 
        username = username || null;
        password = password || null;
    },

    Reminder: function(username, email) { 
        username = username || null;
        email = email || null;
    }
};

...

var x = new On.User();
x.Create();
```

How could I inherit in `User` function from `Request.User`? I've tried it in many different ways but can't make it work (even made a constructor in User's prototype). How could I make it possible to inherit, and call `_Login` from `Login`?

Ps.: this code is just an example, I'm newbie to prototype, and trying to learn it via examples I write.

Comment: With so many articles and posts around the web...

Comment: [This-Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) is a good place to get started.  [This-Javascript “OOP” and prototypes with multiple-level inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040955/javascript-oop-and-prototypes-with-multiple-level-inheritance?rq=1) might help break it into more understandable terms.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown not to mention on this very site...

Comment: http://prntscr.com/6z4mea Come on.

Comment: @briosheje Note that that link appeared when the 2nd comment was posted and linked to it, ie it wasn't there when the 1st comment was written.

Answer (score 0):

You should read proper JS material to get into the mindset of prototypal inheritance. [Follow this list](https://github.com/gruberb/RoadToJavaScript) or [this article](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-objects) for example.

**Your code would look basically like this:**

```
var On = {
  Request: {
    User: function requestUser() { console.log('let me see');}
  },
  User: function user() {}
}

On.User.prototype = On.Request.User();

On.User();
```

*But be aware:* This is not proper JS or how you would structure your app. More of an idea of what you can do.

You can play around [with this code at JSBin](http://jsbin.com/weqimaluyu/1/).

Comment: `On.User.prototype = On.Request.User();`? Oh certainly not.